# Polygon containment

Tags: postgresql, postgis

Data is saved in Postgres database (with PostGIS extension). I have a table which contains columns: pid, geometry, parent. pID is primary key, geometry is geographical data which is described with points and parent column contains a pID of this record's parent.
That means we want in table order like this:

- A, square (geometry), C
- B, square (geometry), C
- C, polygon (geometry), D
- D, polygon (geometry), \

The problem we are facing is how to find the closest/smallest parent polygon if we do not know their initial order. If we process C first, we can then add D as a parent, but if we start with A and B, D is not the correct parent.

[image: Polygon containing]

If you have any suggestion, how to solve this problem I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an extra column with  the area of the geography, and then in your query use `contains`, `within`, `&&` or another contains operation. Finally order desc by this new column and limit 1 to get the parent

For example, a row must be :

- A, square(geometry),C,Area(100),BoundingBox(square)
- B, square(geometry),C,Area(100), BoundingBox(square)
- C ,polygon(geometry), D,Area(2000),BoundingBox(polygon)

The st_area and st_envelope functions can help

The the query  must be

```
Select id 
from Table 
Where st_envelope('parameter') @ BoundingBox 
ORDER BY Area DESC 
LIMIT 1
```

Form postgis docs
http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.3/ST_Geometry_Contained.html

> ```
> @ — Returns TRUE if A's bounding box is contained by B's.
> ```

With `@`  you make the container filter, so you have all the 'parents' that contain the geometry, and then get one of them (order by area)

Comment: Can you explain more precisly, I don't understand what is your idea ?